# How do I find the supremum and infimum of this set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

$S=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}:x^2+x\lt3\rbrace$ is the set.

It says to draw a graph as a hint, but I haven't found it useful. What do I do to find the sup and inf for this set?

Comment: Draw the graph. Why haven't you found it useful?

Answer (score 5):

Simply draw the graph of $y=x^2+x$ and the graph $y=3$, then find all the values of $x$ such that the first graph is below the line $y=3$.

Then once you have found this set of values, it is easy to find the $\sup$ and $\inf$.

Answer (score 2):

Solve for $x^2+x=3$. Ask yourself what happens if a number is smaller or larger than what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that in the expression $(x+a)^2$ we have $2a$ as the coeffiecient of $x$ ($(x-a)^2=x^2+\underline{2a}x+a^2$), so that, half the given coefficient of $x$ and rewrite:
$$x^2+x<3 \ \iff \ \left(x+\frac12\right)^2\ -\frac14 <3 \\
\iff\ \left(x+\frac12\right)^2<3+\frac14  $$
Continue rewriting to equivalent conditions.